# Entity Framework many to many cascading constraints

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

Error: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.TenantUnits_dbo.Units_Unit_Id' on table 'TenantUnits' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I know this error has something to do with the nature of the relationships in my model, but I'm far too confused to sort it out. I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around cascades and many to many relationships that are involved in my model.

Models are as follow:

```
public class Complex
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Unit> Units { get; set; }

    public Complex()
    {
        this.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Units = new HashSet<Unit>();
    }

    public void AddUnit(Unit unit)
    {
        Units.Add(unit);
    }
}

public class Unit
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid ComplexId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ComplexId")]
    public virtual Complex Complex { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }

    public Unit()
    {
        this.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Tenants = new HashSet<Tenant>();
    }

    public void AddTenant(Tenant tenant)
    {
        Tenants.Add(tenant);
    }
}

public class Tenant
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Guid ContactInfoId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ContactInfoId")]
    public ContactInfo ContactInfo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Unit> Units { get; set; }

    public Tenant()
    {
        this.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        this.Units = new HashSet<Unit>();
    }
}

public class Address
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }

    public Address()
    {
        this.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}

public class ContactInfo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid AddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public ContactInfo()
    {
        this.Id = System.Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I resolved the error by adding `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();`
but I still don't fully understand the effects and/or how it's working - or if this is even what I need to use.

Answer (score 0):

An ICollection is used to define a one to many or many to many relationship between entities. In your "Complex" class, you have defined an ICollection of "Unit". But, there is no Foreign key property "UnitId" defined in the Complex class which maps to the primary key of the Unit entity. Entity Framework maps the "Id" of Complex class to "Id" of Unit class. (Assumption: Id of Unit, Complex and Tenant are different). This may be the reason behind the error. Define a "UnitId" property and add a foreign key attribute to the "Units" collection. Similarly, fix your Tenant and Unit class.